# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ConvFrontEnd

Tags: debugging, speech-recognition, transformer-model, speech

https://github.com/villwin/OpenTransformer

(opentransformer) root@autodl-container-69ce11b852-16657c42:~/autodl-tmp/OpenTransformer# python eval.py -m egs/aishell/exp/conformer_transformer_baseline/model.epoch.0.1.000000.pt
2023-05-10 17:14:10,297 - INFO - Build a conv frontend!
2023-05-10 17:14:10,554 - INFO - Build a conformer encoder!
2023-05-10 17:14:10,678 - INFO - Tie the weights between the embedding and output layer.
2023-05-10 17:14:10,678 - INFO - Build a transformer decoder!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "eval.py", line 306, in 
main(cmd_args)
File "eval.py", line 91, in main
model.frontend.load_state_dict(checkpoint['frontend'])
File "/root/miniconda3/envs/opentransformer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1044, in load_state_dict
raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ConvFrontEnd:
Missing key(s) in state_dict: "conv1.U", "conv1.VT", "conv1.bias", "conv2.U", "conv2.VT", "conv2.bias", "output_layer.U", "output_layer.VT".
Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "conv1.conv_layer.weight", "conv1.conv_layer.bias", "conv2.conv_layer.weight", "conv2.conv_layer.bias", "output_layer.weight".

help me!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.